# What arguments should I give when I call the function I created for bind in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, bind

Here is an example of a problem:

```
from  tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

combobox1 = ttk.Combobox(root, values = ('Jan', 'Feb', 'August'))
combobox1.pack()

comb2 = ttk.Combobox(root, state=DISABLED)
comb2.pack()

def comb1_selected(*args):
    someword = "" 
    if combobox1.get() == 'Jan':
        someword = 'J'
        comb2.config(state='normal')
        comb2.config(values=someword)
    return someword

def use_comb1_selected():
    print(comb1_selected(*args))

use_comb1_selected() #What arguments should I give here??

combobox1.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>", comb1_selected)

root.mainloop()
```

I can't figure out which arguments to give to the function I created
Attempting to give arguments like "event" caused the following error

```
    NameError: name 'event' is not defined
```

And without the argument, the function did nothing, even though it was supposed to be printed 'J'

Please help me understand what I need to do

Comment: Function `use_comb1_selected()` does not expect argument, so what do you want to pass to it?  Also function `comb1_selected(*args)` expect any number of arguments (although they are not used inside the function), so you can simply call it without argument.

Comment: Thanks for your response    But on the question I made sure to point out the problematic in what you suggested
Without arguments the function    operation    (which is to print 'J') is not performed

Comment: When you called the function `use_comb1_selected()` which in turn called function `comb1_selected()`, there should be no option is selected in the combobox.  So nothing will be printed.

Comment: So what do you propose to do to use the value 'someword' outside of the 'comb1_selected' function?

Comment: Make it global.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answers
I tried what you suggested
I added the line 'global someword' to the comb1_selected function
But still 'J' is not printed

Comment: As I already said, nothing will be printed if `Jan` is not selected in the combobox when `use_comb1_selected()` is called.  Did you get it?